# Is it possible to Detect Closure Programmatically?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a function which allows user to pass a function.

```
function withPredicate(func){
    //...
}
```

Inside my function, I need to detect whether the func that user pass in has closure or not.

It is not enough to get the function name and search it in window scope. User might pass in an anonymous function without closure like:

```
var func = function(x){return x;};
withPredicate(func);
```

**EDIT:**

I think I need to implement a function which takes a function as a argument and return bool.

```
function hasClosure(func){
    //...
}
```

so several test cases are:

```
hasClosure(function(x){return x;}); //return false

var something = 30;
var func1 = function(x){return x.age < something;} 
hasClosure(func1);   //return false

var Closure = function(){
    var something = 18;
    var itself = function(x){
        return x.age < something;
    };
    return itself;
};

var func2 = new Closure();
hasClosure(func2); //return true
```

The last one return true because func2 is not top-level function. When I see some free variable inside the function body like `something`, it may resolve to the variable defined in its closure other than the one defined in window.

Actually, what I need to do now is to do some manipulations based on the func that has been passed to my function. I can use JSLint to get the undeclared variable. But I also need to resolve these variables. It is acceptable that I can only resolve variables in global scope. But I still need a way to make sure that resolving these variables in global scope is correct. So I need to detect closures.

Is it possible to do that programmatically in javascript?

Comment: Not without a native extension. A `function`'s scope chain isn't exposed within language to react to. Though, out of curiosity, why do you need to know whether the `function` has such a scope associated to it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller perhaps?

Comment: What do you define as a closure? You can get real hacky and chop up `func.toString()` if you want things to get real weird

Comment: I've update the post and I think it is much more clear now. @megawac

Comment: @StarPinkER: What for do you need to detect closures? To check that a given function is side-effect-free or what? There should be no functional difference between the closure and the closure-less function - and that means you should not be able to detect it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't point it out. I've updated my question, can you take a look at it? @Bergi

Comment: What manipulations do you need to do? There might be better ways of achieving that than to eval code in a possibly wrong scope.

Comment: I need to convert the code inside the function into AST and then convert into an intermediate representation. It is complex. I can throw exceptions if I cannot convert. But it would be much better if I can resolve the variable if it is only defined in global scope in the scope chain, and throw exceptions otherwise.

Comment: Semantic closures can be detected by analysis of the source but not, AFAIK, in the runtime environment, which "knows" only of members being in scope or not in scope. Somewhere in the bowels of the js engine there must be some flag (for each execution context) that causes GC to be suppressed, but AFAIK it's not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Alright this is really hacky and probably not worth the effort in actually writing unless your linting or something :)

Basically what you're going to have to do to determine if a function is a closure is call `func.toString()` which will give you the source of the function. You can then parse the function using some sort of parser which determines all the variables of the function `func`. You also need to determine and track how these variables are defined. In your criteria in op the criteria for it being a closure is having a variable that is defined outside of function scope and outside of window scope (thus closure scope). So if you can find any variables defined outside of these two scopes we've found a closure.

So heres the pseudocode of `hasClosure()`, have fun implementing.

```
func hasClosure(func)
   source = func.toString(); //eg "function x(a) {return new Array(a)}"
   variables = parseJSForVariables(source)//finds a and Array
   for variable in variables:
      if(variable not in window)
          if(variable not defined in function)
              return true //we got a closure
  return false //not a closure
```

Comment: What if I found a variable in window, but it still has a outer function scope? Like my last example.

Comment: There is literally no way you can know, javascript does not pass you any information of a functions scope which is why this is really hacky

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer highly depends on what a "closure" means in this context. The function from the question does not use the variables from the outer scope so, roughly, closure is not created for this function. But strictly speaking, closure is created for any function and binds definition context with the function. So whatever you want to detect, it requires a detailed specification.

But I can assume that the closure here means whether the function references variables declared in outer scope (just like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures specifies). One of the static for analysis libraries can be used for this. For example, JSLint reports used but undeclared variables. Assuming that undeclared variables are just from the upper scope, this indicates that closure is created.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't describe my question precisely. I update my post, can you take a look?

Comment: OK. If you check the function Closure with JSLint.com with whitespace and other unrelated checks turned off, you will see the function report. The report includes the inner function, its parameters and outer variables that it uses. It looks for me that analything this report is the good way of building the criteria of whether the function contains a closure. You can build this report for any function in you code, of course - consult JSLint doc for the details.

Comment: But the question is that I can only pass the function the user gives to me to JSLint. So JSLint can no nothing about how that function is built.

Comment: As mentioned in the another answer, use .toString() method of the function to get its source code.